# Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath' when building android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Here is one question when I encountered to deal with the problems as shown
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAeBq.png).
I try to add the `builder-test-api.jar` in `app/libs/ directories` and add the dependency information in app `build.gradle` file [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSiEb.png):

but it still with the problem . How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Is it the latest version? That version may no longer exist.

Comment: 1. Remove dependency from gradle 
2. right click on jar and click on add as library

Comment: After removing dependency from gradle and add as library, it seems got the same error results. It still does not work well !

Comment: I had the same issue. Can you post your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.salil.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

Comment: buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile file ('libs/builder-test-api-0.13.2.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':libraries:opencv')
}